# Show that $f=0$ on $D.$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:D=\{z:|z|<1\}\to\mathbb C$ be analytic on $D$ such that $|f(z)|\le1-|z|$ on $D.$ Show that $f=0$ on $D.$

My thought: If possible let $f$ be nonconstant on $D.$ Choose $0<\epsilon<1.$ Then $0<\delta(=1-\epsilon)<1.$ $f$ is analytic on $\{z:|z|<\delta\}$ and continuous for $|z|=\delta.$ Thus $\displaystyle\max_{|z|\le\delta}|f(z)|$ is attained for $|z|=\delta$ (Since $f$ be nonconstant on $D$ the result follows from maximulm modulus principle). Consequently $\displaystyle\max_{|z|\le\delta}|f(z)|\le1-\delta=\epsilon\implies\displaystyle\max_{|z|\le1-\frac{1}{n}}|f(z)|\le\dfrac{1}{n}.~\forall~n\ge2.$ Then $f=0$ on $D.$ (for otherwise if $f(c)=d>0$ for some $0\le c<1$ then choose $k\ge2$ s.t. $\dfrac{1}{k}<d.$ Then $1-1/k<|c|<1$ since $\displaystyle\max_{|z|\le1-\frac{1}{k}}|f(z)|\le\dfrac{1}{k}<d$ but $1-1/k<|c|<1\implies |f(c)|\le1-|c|<1/k<d!$) But $f$ can't be a constant.

The contradiction implies the $f$ is constant on $D.$ Now along the sequence $x_n=1-\dfrac{1}{n},$  $|f(x_n)|\le\dfrac{1}{n}$ i.e. for there is a point in $D$ whose functional value is less than a chosen positive number. Thus $f=0$ on D.

**Please tell me if it is correct!**

Comment: extend $f$ to $\partial D=\{z:|z|=1\}$ as $f(z)=0$. then from Cauch equation $f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_D\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$, one will get $\forall a\in D, f(a)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but it is not necessary to raise fuss over constant/nonconstant $f$. Let $z_0\in D$. For any $\epsilon \in (0,1-|z_0|)$, applying the maximum principle on  $\{z:|z|<1-\epsilon\}$ yields $|f(z_0)|\le \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ could be arbitrarily small, $f(z_0)=0$. Done.